# Изменить значение глобальной переменной в локальной области без переопределения

Tags: c#

КАК Изменить значение глобальной переменной в локальной области видимости без переопределения

```
int val;
while (sqlReader.Read())
{
    if (textBox_reg_login.Text == sqlReader["login"].ToString())
    {
        label_reg_login_message.Text = "Логин с таким значением уже существует";
        val = 1; //Глобальная переменная переопределяется
        break;
    }
}
if (val == 1)  //И здесь уже ошибка: переменной val не присвоено значение 
{
}
```

Comment: "И здесь уже ошибка" - Умоляю! Какая?!

Comment: @Regent Kонечно. Это был воспитательный комментарий, "чтобы не оттолкнуть нового, неопытного участника". Надеюсь, Николас не увидит его и не откроет на мете обсуждение о недопустимости таких реплик. Интересно, он еще не настроил систему на поиск в комментариях слова "Николас"?

Comment: @Igor, самое интересное, не происходит ли у него ошибки Парсинга, что он после условия кириллицей пишет малоосмысленные слова...

Comment: Какая ошибка? переменной val не присвоено значение

Comment: А для Евгения Иванова ставлю по два слеша

Comment: @user293746 Ну, напишите: `int val = 0;`, действительно же, в Вашем коде переменная останется "без значения", если ридер пустой или условие не выполнится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откуда берётся ошибка, понятно: ведь ничто не гарантирует, что внутри цикла `while` будет присвоено значение переменной `val`. А чтение неинициализированной переменной в языке не разрешено.

Инициализируйте `val` каким-то значением до цикла.

---

И кстати, у вас `val`, судя по всему, локальная переменная. Поля классов (как простые, так и статические) инициализируются по умолчанию значением `default` соответствующего типа.

Comment: Всем спасибо! Походу я сегодня уже туплю!

Comment: Такой детский вопрос)))

Comment: @user293746 если ответ вас устраивает, то не забудьте отметить его как подходящий (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: @user293746: Пожалуйста! Простые вопросы тоже важны.